# Weight being added instead of reduced when painting

Tags: weight-painting

I've been trying to fix this issue for a while and i'm not sure if its a bug or if there's a way around it, a wrong part of an object was weight painted so i tried to erase/reduce the weight but it kept on adding more weight even if the brush weight was at 0.000[image: The weight on the bottom is the one that i cannot erase/reduce]

Comment: do you have the Auto Normalize option enabled?

Comment: yes i do have auto normalize enabled

Comment: so does it fix your problem if you disable it? Not sure why it is set this way though

Comment: nope i tried,it's still the same as it was before

Comment: maybe share this part of your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i just re-made this part all over again and it works now, not sure what the problem was before but thanks for the help

Comment: oh ok then........   ;)